# stop openfire log rotation

Tags: logging, rotation, openfire

Hello I am using openfire 3.6.4 and it has mechanism to rotate log files (info.log, debug.log etc) which is size based and time based but I have mechanism for log files rotation so i want to disable openfire's log rotation mechanism, so can anybody suggest me how to stop the openfire's log rotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Openfire you can increase the maximum size of the log (info.log, warn.log, etc). Try to increase it to 1Gb or more (config maxsize log in wildfire.xml).

See http://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1061